# What is the meaning of paw-printed in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "paw-printed" mean in this sentence?

> Enter for a chance to win one of three free autographed (paw-printed) first-edition copies...

As much as I understand the meaning of both paw and print I do not understand it perfectly in this context.

Does it mean the author, itself, is going to be signing the book. Also I would assumed in this case "autographed" would be enough to state that.

Or is it that they're going to use a stamp, like some do, which mean it will not be a proper autograph as such using paw-printed here to indicate it would not be a clean autograph?

Comment: Is it talking about a book that purports to be written by a cat or a dog? That's the only way I can make sense of that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author, [Jaxy Mono](http://www.jaxymono.com/), is (or pretends to be) a monkey. From [Goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29966140-thirty-three):

> Jaxy Mono - the world famous “monkey with a typewriter” and the creator of “monkey lit” - is a highly intelligent tail-less Barbary Ape (Macaca sylvanus) from Europe’s only population of wild monkeys in Gibraltar.